# run java code on docker

Tags: java, unix, docker, dockerfile

I try to run java code on docker but I got an error that I could not solve could you please help me?!

I have a very simple java code which is to calculate the average.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Ave
{
     public static void main(String args[])

     {

          int n;
          double res=0;

      Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to calculate the avrage ");

          n=reader.nextInt();

      int a[]=new int[n];

      System.out.println("Enter   "+n+"  numbers");

          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           a[i]= (int) reader.nextDouble(); 

      res=Ave.CalAvg(a,n); 

      System.out.println("The average is " +res/n);

     }

       static double CalAvg(int  a[],int n)
       {
       double res=0;

       for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           res =res+a[i];

       return res;
        }
}
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD Ave.class Ave.class
RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "Ave"]
```

What I did that I compiled this file using the Java compiler.

```
$ javac Ave.java
```

I used below command to build an image from this Dockerfile

```
$ docker build --tag "docker-hello-world:latest" .
```

Then, I tried to run the Docker image to see the result by executing the below command.

```
$ docker run docker-hello-world:latest
```

Finally, I got this error or exception which I could not figure out

**The code is run on the server and local machine but it does not work on docker**

```
Enter how many numbers to calculate the avrage 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Ave.main(Ave.java:17)
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnPNs.jpg)

Comment: Try `docker run -it docker-hello-world`.

Comment: @SiKing It does not work too. [ Enter how many numbers to calculate the avrage 
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 at Ave.main(Ave.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher... ]

Comment: @YazeedAlqahhas I tried with `docker run -it docker-hello-world:latest` and it worked for me, i used the exact `java` source code you provided and the exact `Dockerfile`. Check your `java` class source code, the error looks like you added more code to it and is different from what you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

My env: Mac-Os Sierra-10.12.6

Docker version:

```
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24
```

To Check Java version in container:

1. execute `$docker run -it docker-hello-world:latest`
2. get ContainerID by executing `$docker ps`
3. get shell of docker image `docker exec -i -t <CONTAINER ID>`
4. Execute following command

   $java -version

> openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.6.0) (Alpine 8.151.12-r0)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

Create a directory (anyname here I gave `a`), I created at Desktop,

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir a
```

create `Ave.java` file in `~/Desktop/a` directory

Also, have Dockerfile in the same directory(/a)

Considering there is no package name in Ave.java

```
$javac Ave.java
```

now
folder /a will have 3 files, Ave.java, Ave.class, Dockerfile

Execute following command

```
$docker build -t docker-hello-world:latest .
```

Console Logs:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/4 : ADD Ave.class Ave.class
 ---> 8b94ae6de674
Step 3/4 : RUN apk --update add openjdk8-jre
 ---> Running in f12eb4589a34
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/39) Installing libffi (3.2.1-r4)
(2/39) Installing libtasn1 (4.12-r3)
(3/39) Installing p11-kit (0.23.2-r2)
(4/39) Installing p11-kit-trust (0.23.2-r2)
(5/39) Installing ca-certificates (20171114-r0)
(6/39) Installing java-cacerts (1.0-r0)
(7/39) Installing libxau (1.0.8-r2)
(8/39) Installing libbsd (0.8.6-r1)
(9/39) Installing libxdmcp (1.1.2-r4)
(10/39) Installing libxcb (1.12-r1)
(11/39) Installing libx11 (1.6.5-r1)
(12/39) Installing libxcomposite (0.4.4-r1)
(13/39) Installing libxext (1.3.3-r2)
(14/39) Installing libxi (1.7.9-r1)
(15/39) Installing libxrender (0.9.10-r2)
(16/39) Installing libxtst (1.2.3-r1)
(17/39) Installing alsa-lib (1.1.4.1-r2)
(18/39) Installing libbz2 (1.0.6-r6)
(19/39) Installing libpng (1.6.34-r1)
(20/39) Installing freetype (2.8.1-r2)
(21/39) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r5)
(22/39) Installing giflib (5.1.4-r1)
(23/39) Installing libjpeg-turbo (1.5.2-r0)
(24/39) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r5)
(25/39) Installing openjdk8-jre-lib (8.151.12-r0)
(26/39) Installing java-common (0.1-r0)
(27/39) Installing krb5-conf (1.0-r1)
(28/39) Installing libcom_err (1.43.7-r0)
(29/39) Installing keyutils-libs (1.5.10-r0)
(30/39) Installing libverto (0.3.0-r0)
(31/39) Installing krb5-libs (1.15.2-r1)
(32/39) Installing lcms2 (2.8-r1)
(33/39) Installing nspr (4.17-r0)
(34/39) Installing sqlite-libs (3.21.0-r0)
(35/39) Installing nss (3.34.1-r0)
(36/39) Installing pcsc-lite-libs (1.8.22-r0)
(37/39) Installing lksctp-tools (1.0.17-r0)
(38/39) Installing openjdk8-jre-base (8.151.12-r0)
(39/39) Installing openjdk8-jre (8.151.12-r0)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r7.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20171114-r0.trigger
Executing java-common-0.1-r0.trigger
OK: 81 MiB in 50 packages
Removing intermediate container f12eb4589a34
 ---> 82d9ecfcc95e
Step 4/4 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "Ave"]
 ---> Running in 28f2df6fb544
Removing intermediate container 28f2df6fb544
 ---> bbf098575e6a
Successfully built bbf098575e6a
Successfully tagged docker-hello-world:latest
```

Execute command as suggested by @Siking

```
$docker run -it docker-hello-world:latest
```

here is snapshot of output:
[image]

Comment: @SiKing @dkb I have the same problem `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 at Ave.main(Ave.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 ... 1 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.Class.....`

Comment: @YazeedAlqahhas, Do you mean, you are still facing issue after trying as I mentioned above?

Comment: @SiKing @dkb Yes I do and I don't know if the Docker version caused that. my Docker version is `17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`. Also, My java version is `openjdk version "9-internal" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)`

Comment: @YazeedAlqahhas, I don't think your system's java version is an issue since java version is openjdk8-jre in an image (as mention in Dockerfile) if you think docker version is an issue, better upgrade and test.