# Run java in docker using dockerfile

Tags: java, docker, visual-studio-code

I want to run a java program with tests, in the **docker** using VS code environment.

Here is the file structure:

```
. 
├── src
│   └── Calculator.java
│   └── Main.java
└── test
    └── CalculatorTest.java
```

The content:

Calculator.java:

```
public class Calculator {

public Calculator() {
}

public double calc(char operator, double firstNum, double secondNum) throws Exception {
    if(operator=='/'&secondNum==0)
        throw new  Exception("Cannot div with 0!");
    return switch (operator) {
        case ('+') -> firstNum + secondNum;
        case ('-') -> firstNum - secondNum;
        case ('/') -> firstNum / secondNum;
        case ('*') -> firstNum * secondNum;
        default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + operator);
    };
}

public double calcStr(String str) {
    try {
        str = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        double sum = 0;
        double lastApplyOpRes = 0;
        double lastNum = 0;
        double len = str.length();
        char prevOperator = '+';
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                lastNum = lastNum * 10 + c - '0';
                continue;
            }
            lastApplyOpRes = calc(prevOperator, lastApplyOpRes, lastNum);
            lastNum = 0;
            switch (c) {
                case '+':
                case '-':
                    sum += lastApplyOpRes;
                    lastApplyOpRes = 0;
                    break;
            }
            prevOperator = c;
        }
        lastApplyOpRes = calc(prevOperator, lastApplyOpRes, lastNum);
        return sum + lastApplyOpRes;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("Hello to calculator!");
   }
}
```

CalculatoTest.java:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class CalculatorTest {

Calculator calculator;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    calculator = new Calculator();
}

@Test
void testEmpty() {
    assertEquals(0, calculator.calcStr(""));
}

@Test
void testOneNum() {
    assertEquals(5, calculator.calcStr("5"));
}

@Test
void testPlus() {
    assertEquals(8, calculator.calcStr("5+3"));
}

@Test
void testMul() {
    assertEquals(15, calculator.calcStr("5*3"));
}

@Test
void testMulPlus() {
    assertEquals(8, calculator.calcStr("2*3+2"));
}

@Test
void testPlusMul() {
    assertEquals(11, calculator.calcStr("2+3*3"));
}

@Test
void testPlusMulPlus() {
    assertEquals(16, calculator.calcStr("2+3+3*3+2"));
}

@Test
void testMinus() {
    assertEquals(2, calculator.calcStr("5-3"));
}

@Test
void testDivision() {
    assertEquals(2, calculator.calcStr("6/3"));
}

@Test
void testMinusPlus() {
    assertEquals(1, calculator.calcStr("2-3+2"));
}

@Test
void testPlusDivide() {
    assertEquals(5, calculator.calcStr("3+4/2"));
}

@Test
void testAll() {
    assertEquals(6, calculator.calcStr("2-3+3/3+2*3"));
}

@Test
void testDivZero(){
    assertEquals(0, calculator.calcStr("8/0"));
}
}
```

I wrote all this to create a program that simulates a calculator,
I added tests to test the function that simulates a calculator.
I want to know how to run the tests and everything in Docker,
I prefer a solution using dockerfile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Bela, Did you try creating DockerFile for your jar and running the resulting image in docker ?

Comment: I don't know how to write a suitable Dockerfile for this program, so I need your help - thanks!

Comment: FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
COPY path/ypur_app.jar  app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]

Comment: Its rather straightforward https://www.baeldung.com/java-dockerize-app

Comment: (Consider removing the `try`/`catch` block in your code – in the last test, `8/0` _should_ be an exception and not zero.)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I only have `.java` files and not `.jar` files, what I wrote in the Dockerfile was: `FROM openjdk
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/dir
WORKDIR /usr/src/dir
COPY Main.java ./
COPY . ./
RUN javac Main.java
CMD java Main`
And it only ran the MAIN page for me.
How do you run the TEST?
Do I need to add an XML file?

Comment: I put the dockerfile in the src folder.

Comment: @Bela in that case you need to  put the .class file in your image, The compiled file

Comment: @SanyamGoel-Thanks! But when I put the dockerfile in the test folder I got this error:`package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist` How can I add this package? To where?

Comment: I will explain what I did - I createda project in intelij and then I wanted to run it in the vs code environment by Docker.
That's why I copied the classes I wrote, but I don't have the whole shell of the project like in intelij. What else do I need to add for it to run well (including the tests)?

Comment: @Bela export the project as a jar file. Then use docker file to create a docker image from this jar and finally you can run this image

Comment: When you craeate a jar, junit jar can be packaged in this jar to be available on the classpath

Comment: @SanyamGoel Thanks for your help - but I still don't know how to do it, maybe you can attach a solution for this?

Comment: @Bela here you go, tested the image it works https://github.com/sanyamgoel1988/calculator.git

Comment: download the zip, Enter the folder containing dockerfile and the jar. next run 
docker build -t calculator:v1 .  command and then docker run calculator:v1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run java code on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951042/run-java-code-on-docker)

Comment: @SanyamGoel Huge thanks!!!
Thanks for taking the effort to write a solution and upload it for me!!
How can I see the contents of the JAR?
And another question if possible - how to run the tests?

Comment: @Bela, Contents of the jar are in compiled form, It contains the 2 classes and a junit file you provided, will upload that too. 
Test case execution is a build time activity not a runtime activity. So your executing program has very really nothing to do with the execution of test cases

Comment: In a normal scenario for example, The test cases are executed during the jar/image building process by tools like jenkins, gitlab etc and on success the jar is packaged in a docker image